# What do the different forms of 있다 mean?

Tags: verb-endings, verb, conjugation

`있다` means:

- to be
- to lie
- to take place

In the text book I only learnt `있어요`

While watching K-dramas, I saw SOOOO many forms that I've no idea what they mean:

- `있어`: Is this because the `요` is dropped?
- `있는`, `있을`: I thought `~는` and `~을`was for nouns only.
- `있지`: What does `~지` mean?
- `있는데`: What does `~는데` mean?
- `있습니다`: Is this the formal form?
- `있어서`: What does `~어서 mean?

There are many many more? How would one know what they all mean?

Answer (score 1):

These are all different grammar forms, and thus they give a certain meaning to 있다 when attached to the verb-stem. I recommend you to start learning Korean grammar from e.g. [www.talktomeinkorean.com](http://www.talktomeinkorean.com) or [www.howtostudykorean.com](http://www.howtostudykorean.com), as your question is quite basic.

You can find out what all of them mean by using the guides on those websites.